# How to find the corners of a checkerboard pattern with SIFT algorithm?

Tags: opencv, sift

First, I can use the OpenCV API **findChessboardCorners** and **cornerSubPix** to find the corners on an checkerboard pattern, like this:
[image]

But i want to improve the accuracy of corners location and I learn that the SIFT has the highest precision. So, I want to try the SIFT by the code like this:

```
Mat img = imread("chess.jpg", 0);
if (img.cols > 800) {
    resize(img, img, Size(800, (int)(800.0 / img.cols * img.rows)));
}

vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

Ptr<xfeatures2d::SIFT> sift = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();

sift->detect(img, keypoints);
Mat feature;
cv::drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, feature, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

imshow("feature", feature);
```

but the result doesn't meet my expectations. The result is this:
[image]

So, can anybody tell me the right way of using SIFT? Any information is expected .Thanks!

Comment: Do not use SIFT, this is not the right tool for what you want to achieve: `findChessboardCorners` + `cornerSubPix` is the correct approach IMHO.

Comment: @Catree Thank you, May be you are right from what I have learn about SIFT.